# Example of a diffeomorphism from all of $\mathbb{R}$ to itself

Tags: real-analysis, functions, differential-topology

I can think of diffeomorphisms from an interval to $(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, scaling the tangent function, and from the punctured plane, polar coordinates, or some odd polynomial, but does anyone have a nontrivial example that doesn't break down at the origin?

Comment: I'm guessing you want a non-trivial one?

Comment: Any linear map, any affine transformation. Multiplication by a nonzero real.

Comment: What do you mean "break down at the origin"?

Comment: yeah I was wondering if there was a nonlinear map. I wanted the differentiable inverse to be defined for x=0. And by break down at the origin i meant the way that polar coordinates are not well defined at the origin, or how $f(x)=x^3$ is a diffeomorphism but whose inverse is not defined at the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most trivial example is the identity map $f(x)=x$.  Slightly less trivial are linear polynomials $f(x)=ax+b$ (for $a\neq 0$).

A less trivial but still simple example is $f(x)=x^3+x$.  Since $f'(x)=3x^2+1$ is positive everywhere, $f$ is strictly increasing and thus injective.  Since $f(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, $f$ must be a bijection, and it is thus a diffeomorphism since its derivative never vanishes.

Comment: The second one is perfect. I appreciate it, not sure why i didnt think of it.

Comment: I didn't get it - how do we know that $f^{-1}$ is smooth?

Comment: @S.R: That's by the inverse function theorem.  If a smooth map has invertible derivative at a point, then it has a smooth inverse when restricted to some neighborhood of that point.